# Where do I find info on how does SP use its private key to sign the authentication request and sends it to the URL at the IdP?

Tags: saml-2.0, signing

I have been reading a book about SAML 2.0 lately. There was a point in regards to the "typical use and usefulness of SAML metadata" stating the following:

> The SP wants to authenticate a user. It looks at the metadata and finds the URL at the IdP where users should be sent. It uses its private key to sign the authentication request and sends it to the URL at the IdP.

The line I am interested the most (and the one I do not well understand yet...) is:

> It uses its private key to sign the authentication request and sends it to the URL at the IdP.

My question is - where exactly in any of the existing standard/RFC/alike document may I find info on these exact points mentioned in the SAML book - signing, calling?

For example, it is not clear for me if that's the call signed by a standard HTTPS process or is it SAML-specific-signing + HTTPS, what type of algorithm is in use at signing, what kind of call should happen (GET, POST, other), what kind of parameters (if that's important at all) should be sent with the call... and alike questions related to signing and sending arise. I expect a document of some kind to get into more details and explain signing and calling procedures. Not much success on finding precise pages in right documents yet. Seems like RFC 2818 may be a good direction, or one of many SAML 2.0 specifications, or else.

Pointing to (the part of) the right document containing the info on the signing and the calling would be appreciated. Elaborating a bit on the given quote I do not understand would also benefit a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of questions - Not surprising as SAML is a large topic. And there are a lot of documents.  Take a look at the following link as it would walk someone through integrating perl's Net::SAML2 into a web application and walks through the steps.

https://github.com/perl-net-saml2/perl-Net-SAML2/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md

However it does gloss over some things.  Early on it says:

The IdP object contains the Identity Providers settings that were parse from the metadata and are then used for the rest of the calls.

In that you see a

```
'sso_urls' => {
                                 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=CXXXXXXXX',
                                 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=CXXXXXXXX'
                               },
```

If you ignore the 40+ page doc on metadata https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf These are the two methods the IdP used for the sign on and specified a HTTP-Redirect and a POST method.  IN this case the URL's match but they do not need to.

The creation of the HTTP-Redirect for the AuthnRequest alone is a minor feat. https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf.  Page 15  3.4 HTTP Redirect Binding describes the method.  It is essentially taking the XML AuthnRequest and using the DEFLATE compression method (see
[RFC1951]) The result is Base64 encoded and assigned to SAMLResponse and has the RelayState (if any) and SigAlg appended as GET request parameters.  The result is Signed using a accepted algorithim like rsa-sha256 and the base 64 signature is added to the query parameter that are normally URL encoded to be requested via the browser.  See https://github.com/perl-net-saml2/perl-Net-SAML2/blob/064f718178c3fa6edfe0b262fe4b5e4c8705411b/lib/Net/SAML2/Binding/Redirect.pm#L117

So, learning it is walking through each part of the process.  There are multiple documents that address certain parts.  It relies heavily on other existing standards and RFCs.  For instance the POST request and much of the communication uses xml-dsig unlike the HTTP-Request (space limitation in URLs).  That is a beast in itself.

I support Net::SAML2 and can answer specific questions.  Despite its size SAML is a fairly simple (yet extraordinarily complex) protocol.  I quite like it

Answer (score 0):

I think it is my book you are referring to =) [SAML 2.0: Designing secure identity federation](https://shop.samlsecurity.com/b/fGWSH)

SAML is not straight forward and simple so you are not alone in having difficulty in grasping it. You have a lot of questions but I will try and answer them as best I can.

How SAML messages are sent is called bindings. For example POST or Redirect. These are defined in the [bindings spec](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35387/sstc-saml-bindings-errata-2.0-wd-05-diff.pdf) and discussed in chapter 6 of the book.

SAML traffic should always use HTTPS, but in addition the XML should be singing to protect the message from tampering in the browser as HTTPS does not protect against this. The difference between these are discussed under *Transport and message protection* in chapter 12 of the book.

What messages are sent how they are sent and and how they need to be protected in SSO is defined in the Web Browser SSO Profile in the [profiles spec](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35389/sstc-saml-profiles-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf) and discussed in chapter 8 of the book.

How signatures are processed and formats are defined in chapter 5.4 of the [SAML core spec](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35711/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf)

I hope this helps to guide you right.